# GoDaddy SSL not working on sub domains in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb, godaddy-api, aws-acm

I have a SSL certificate from GoDaddy, I've imported that Certificate in ACM. But when I use that certificate with an Application Load Balancer it's not working with subdomain

- example.com - Working
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - Working
- api.example.com - Showing unsecured

In GoDaddy's DNS manager I have added a CNAME for api.example.com with ALB's URL

Thank you!

Comment: Does the certificate specifically include either `*.examplle.com` or `api.example.com`? Subdomains have to be included in the certificate at time of certificate creation.

Comment: No, I can't see above subdomain in the certificate

Comment: That is your problem them. Why even use GoDaddy on AWS ACM, instead of creating the certificate for free in ACM?